# FluentValidation Validators inside RuleSet does not get executed

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

I have a validator with a ruleset

```
public class ApplicationValidator : AbstractValidator<Application>
{
    public ApplicationValidator()
    {
        RuleSet("CreateApplication", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(a => a.SalesChannelBroker)
                .SetValidator(new BrokerActiveRule());

            RuleFor(ld => ld.LoanDetailSegment)
                .SetValidator(new ProductCodeValidRule());
        });
    }
}
```

However the rules are not validated when I execute validation as follows, why?

```
// Validate
var validationResult = new ApplicationValidator().Validate(app, ruleSet: "CreateApplication");
```

Answer (score 1):

What do your `BrokerActiveRule` and `ProductCodeValidRule` validators look like?
Are the rule/s defined in them within the `CreateApplication` rule set?

If they are not within a rule set, or in a rule set other than `CreateApplication`, they won't be invoked.

The child validator behaviour I still find a bit weird, but basically if you invoke a parent validator with a rule set, and you want your child validators to be invoked, the inclusion (`SetValidator` in this case) must be within the rule set, **and** the child validator rules you want to apply must also be within that rule set.

See [this](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/194) for more info.

This behaviour can be customized by creating your own `IValidatorSelector`. This was something that I was looking into doing (but haven't got round to yet) as I have a case where the child validator has default and rule set specific rules meaning I had to include the child validator twice in the parent validator.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, github link guide me to solution. Need to add default in ruleSet to validate child validator.

`var validationResult = new ApplicationValidator().Validate(app, ruleSet: "CreateApplication", "default");`

Hope it will help someone facing the same issue.

Comment: What if I want to exclude default rules?